# VB.NET Share a panel to another application

Tags: vb.net

Lets say I have two windows form applications written in vb.NET, App1 and App2.
App1 and 2 are two completely separated solutions.

Is it possible to share a panel(or another container) in App1 so that App2 can control the content of this panel?
By control the content i mean add textboxs and buttons that will trigger events in App2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have perform that duty before at my enterprise and we use some WinAPI to communicate between windows:

You have to DLLImport the following user32.dll functions:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer

    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, _
    ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
```

You use the SendMessage function from App1 to send the message to App2.

You can **listen** to Window messages overriding the WndProc Sub in the App2 application:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

    If m.Msg = WM_COPYDATA Then
        'Read the message and perform some task,
        'Create textboxes, modify controls, whatever

    Else
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End If
End Sub
```

An example to **send** the Window Message through the Application 1 would be the following:

```
    Dim hWnd As IntPtr
    Dim mCopyData As COPYDATASTRUCT

    hWnd = FindWindow(Nothing, App2WindowName)
    Dim message As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    If (hWnd <> 0) Then

        message.Append(Mensaje)

        Dim pCopyData As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(message.Length() + 40)


        mCopyData.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(message.ToString)
        mCopyData.cbData = message.Length
        mCopyData.dwData = _messageID
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(mCopyData, pCopyData, False)

        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, sender.Handle, pCopyData)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(mCopyData.lpData)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pCopyData)
    End If
```

You need to declare in your code the COPYDATASTRUCT to use the winapi:

```
 <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure COPYDATASTRUCT
        Public dwData As IntPtr
        Public cbData As Integer
        Public lpData As IntPtr
    End Structure
```

and the WM_COPYDATE message integer:

```
 Const WM_COPYDATA As Integer = 74
```

Comment: Thnx for the quick answer. If I understand your solution correctly this will only give me the option of sending text strings between the two applications?

Comment: You can send the message that you need/want. In the example I am marshaling a string to set the lpData but you can use the message you want. They are a lot of predefined messages in windows api. Check this list:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#system_defined

Comment: In this case we are using WM_COPYDATA message type to send a string, but you can send the message you want

Comment: @CarlosLanderas - Wouldn't it be easier to send/listen data on a local arbitrary port? Then you can just roll your own local API?

Comment: Sockets are another option yes. But I prefer not having listening ports on some kind of application. I suppose it depends on what you need. I would not implement a listening port to paint controls and panels.

Comment: Thnx. I will give this a try later on.